# What would be the lowest possible cabin altitude (respectively, highest possible pressure on board) of an airliner in 1155 Pa exterior pressure?

Tags: boeing-737, cabin-pressure, acs-pressurization

How well does an airliner's pressurization work at extremely high altitudes (extremely low atmospheric pressure)? Does the system provide an absolute pressure differential, or is the differential a factor of the ambient pressure?

For example, consider an airliner in an environment where the atmospheric pressure is 1155 Pa (0.1675 psi). Such an environment may be found at an altitude of approximately 100,000 ft on Earth, or in the Hellas Basin on Mars. What cabin altitude could the airliner simulate?

When at 41,000 ft (pressure 2.6 psi) above the Earth's sea level an airliner simulates a cabin altitude of 8,000 ft (10.9 psi), which is 4.19 times the pressure of 2.6 psi at FL410. So if we took $0.1675 \times 4.19$ it would mean an airliner could provide an onboard pressure of 0.7 psi, the pressure around 68,000 ft MSL. Is it correct to assume that you have to multiply by 4.19 to get the result or did I miss something?

Comment: This is borderline off topic for me as you are asking about an impossible situation. An airliner cannot get to the altitudes where they would experience near vacuum.

Comment: Are you asking about structural integrity of the airframe or about the engine's capability to provide the pressurized air?

Comment: @GdD But it's an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: @Bianfable Only about providing pressurized air if it were possible (which it isn't but that doesn't matter).

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how airliner pressurization works.

Comment: @GdD Possible. An answer could help in this matter.

Comment: @Giovanni I don't understand what you expect us to say about "providing pressurized air if it were possible (which it isn't but that doesn't matter)". If it's not possible, how can we write a meaningful answer? Such speculation is off-topic.

Comment: @Bianfable It's only about the pressure in the cabin. I'm asking on a B737 that is on Mars' surface, i.e. not flying, possibly driving. Alternatively you can think of a B737 flying slightly below 100K ft altitude above Earth but that's even less possible. The question is what cabin altitude/pressure could be generated when the exterior pressure is 1155 Pa / 0.1675 psi.

Comment: I think it's far more possible to get a Boeing 737 up to 100 thousand feet than get it to the surface of mars @Giovanni.

Comment: @GdD No, both is equally (im)possible, but it's far more possible that a B737 is standing on solid ground than flying through near-vacuum.

Comment: So you think it is more possible to transport an airliner through millions of miles of space then soft-land it on the surface of another planet that barely has a shred of an atmosphere than it would be to get it up to 100,000ft above our own planet?

Comment: @GdD and upvoter The plane would need to fly on its own at 100K ft which is impossible, but the _how_ is completely irrelevant, my question is about the _if_. Theoretical questions should be allowed.

Comment: @Bianfable and others: the question seems to boil down to **How does an airliner pressurization system work? What is its maximum altitude? How will performance degrade above its maximum altitude?** These questions may or may not be duplicates of others on the site, and may or may not require splitting into separate posts, but they seem on-topic to aviation. +1.

Comment: @randomhead I appreciate your effort to make the question on-topic. I'm still not entirely convinced that there is a non-speculative answer to the question, but I retracted my close vote...

Comment: @Bianfable I had already deleted almost all references on Mars before randomhead's edit. But I'm thanking him due to the even better expression now.

Comment: @Giovanni - Which impossible things are you willing to ignore? If pressurized air comes from bleed air from the engines then the engines must be running. 737 engines won’t run in the Mars atmosphere.  And I‘m pretty sure they’d wouldn’t be able to run at 100,000 ft on Earth. Without them you get no pressurization.

Comment: It would have been better if users countered my arguments against their nonsensical protests rather than sticking to their downvotes and stubborness in that they're simply correct without dealing with most obvious things and the question itself.

Comment: @Jim That could have been part of an answer. But it's also impossible to run an engine at FL1000 even if the atmosphere was 100% oxygen.

Comment: @Giovanni - I think the answer cannot be given yet, because we don’t know the assumptions we can make.  The question needs to be clarified.

Comment: Sea level pressure in PSI is 14.7.  If you are in space and are holding sea level cabin the differential would be 14.7 - 0 (or very close to it) = 14.7 PSID.  The space shuttle must withstand a differential near this value

Answer (score 1):

PSI differential (pounds per square inch) is relative, so the *difference* in psi is comparable as you suggested.  So you can do around 10.9 - 2.6 + .1675
or around 8.4675 psi or around 13,000 feet.  This is a bit better than 68,000 feet, which is above the [Armstrong limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_limit) where full space suits must be worn.

But why not check out what the Virgin Galactic Spaceship 2, New Shephard, Dream Chaser, or Space Shuttle could do.

Any rapid decompression of an airliner cabin would be almost instantly fatal to unprotected passengers under those conditions$^1$. Forget about dropping oxygen masks, air pressure on Mars is way to low to get sufficient O2 into your body, even breathing pure oxygen, unless you have a pressurized suit.

Shuttle astronauts routinely worked in shirt sleeves throughout much of their missions.

$^1$ even if a 737 was capable of doing it

Comment: Metal bodied airliners are generally limited to about 8+ psi differential. The carbon 787 goes to 10 as do some high altitude corporate airplanes.  8.3 psi gives you an 8000 ft cabin at 41000 ft.